# The necessity of defining complexified vector space from an existing real vector space of finite dimension

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $(V,\mathbb{R})$ be a real vector space of finite dimension given to us. As it is finite there always exists a basis of $V$, denoted $\mathcal{B}=\{e_i|i=1,…,n\}$ such that $V=\text{Span}(\mathcal{B})$. Why cannot $V_\mathbb{C}$ be simply defined as $V_\mathbb{C}=\text{Span}_\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{B})$ ignoring the fact that scalar multiplication only makes sense when the field is $\mathbb{R}$?

The way presented to me from a more reliable source is that instead of the above process, we construct from $(V,\mathbb{R})$ the vector space $(\mathbb{C}\otimes V,\mathbb{R})$, then **define** a new scalar multiplicaiton when the scalar is a complex number by $\alpha(\beta\otimes v):=\alpha\beta\otimes v$. And we call the set $\mathbb{C}\otimes V$ equipped with this newly defined multiplication with complex field the complexified vector space of $V$, denoted $V_\mathbb{C}$.

It is as if this entire construction is to avoid the operation of multiplying a complex number **directly** with any vector in the original vector space $V$, and instead make the multiplication become one that we could understand, i.e. by scalar multiplication in the field of complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ as in the first component of $\mathbb{C}\otimes V$. However in doing so we still need to **define** a new multiplication rule which essentially violates the bilinearity requirement of tensor product. So why cannot it be done just by $\text{Span}_\mathbb{C}(\mathcal{B})$ if we are to define some new multiplication rule anyways, we could define a new operation for complex numbers scalar multiplied with vectors in $V$ just as we did in the $\mathbb{C}\otimes V$ case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

But what would ${\rm Span}_\mathbb{C}({\cal B})$ mean if a multiplication by scalars in $\mathbb{C}$ is not defined in $V$?

If you do not want to enlarge $V$ (as with the $V\otimes\mathbb C$ construction) in order to define a complex structure on $V$ you need to give a linear transformation
$$
T:V\longrightarrow V
$$
such that $T^2=-{\rm Id}$ and let
$$
(x+yi)v=x+yT(v)\qquad\forall v\in V, x, y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Equivalently, this amounts to fixing a group homomorphism
$$
\mathbb{C}^\times\longrightarrow{\rm GL}(V).
$$
This cannot always be done: $V$ needs to have an even dimension over $\mathbb{R}$.